# Hashing with random salt in c#?

Tags: c#, php, hash, salt

I'm using the [CryptSharp Library](https://github.com/ChrisMcKee/cryptsharp) in my .NET (C#) client to hash a user's password with a randomly generated salt (Blowfish).

I then proceed to send the hashed password to my remote server where it is stored in a MySQL database.

When I attempt to login with the same plain text password there is a hash mismatch between what is sent and what is stored in the database. (Most likely due to the salt changing each time)

I do not want to send an unencrypted plain-text password to my PHP end, how can I achieve this without using a static salt?

**Hashing (C#):**

```
string passHash = Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt(Password.Text, Crypter.Blowfish.GenerateSalt());
```

I'd prefer not to have to create a new column to store the client's salt at registration, but if I must I will.

Comment: Why are you using Blowfish? There are other more straightforward ways to generate hashes directly from the .NET framework. So, is there any specific reason why you're using Blowfish?

Comment: If not Bcrypt(Blowfish) what would you recommend?

Comment: Use SHA1Managed from .NET framework, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple and un-related to the language being used:

1. If you want the server to store hashed passwords in a database, you can store them with any hashing function (I'd recommend SHA256 or BCrypt if you want to make brute-forcing take longer. The benefit to BCrypt is the salt and number of iterations is stored in the hash directly so requires no extra column in your database).
2. If you want to salt them, you'll need to store a salt column and transmit it to the client to use during hashing. Generally you'll use a random salt for each user, and it will only change when the password is changed. This is recommended but not required - it makes rainbow table attacks useless.
3. If you're worried about transmission over the wire, and not particularly about your database, you can generate a random salt on the server during authentication and only use it that one time - but the server will need the original password for comparison.

You can also combine all of these methods, although i don't think this is standard practice anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var result = string.Empty;
using (var sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
{
    result = ToHex(sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password.Text)));
}
```

Where `ToHex` looks like this:

```
public static string ToHex(byte[] bytes)
{
    return string.Concat(bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
}
```

The previous code does produce the same hash when called multiple times without requiring a salt to be involved.

There are other more secure versions of the SHA algorithm supported in the .NET framework such as `SHA256Managed`. Using SHA1 or SHA256 depends on your security requirements.

Comment: This is an extremely unsafe way to store passwords, neither is the hash salted, nor are there iterations to control the necessary time for hashing. Such hashes can be brute-forced ways too easily (about 5 Giga / sec).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a crypted password is to securely store the password in the database. CryptSharp won't help you with securing transmission over the wire.

There are a number of approaches you could take, but the easiest is probably to communicate with the server over SSL. If you don't want to use a public CA, use a self-signed certificate and hook ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback to accept your own CA or certificate.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer the password from the client to the server, one needs an encrypted HTTPS/SSL connection. It will encrypt the user input before sending it to the client, so a ManInTheMiddle cannot eavesdrop. The hashing must be done on server side, at least a part of the hashing.

The CryptSharp supports the common storage format, and includes the salt in the resulting hash. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to exist a method for verification, which would extract the used salt, at least I couldn't find one.

Another library I can recommend is [BCrypt.Net](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/), there the salt is also stored together with the hash (no need for an extra field) and the verification is very straightforward: `BCrypt.Verify(password, stored_hash)`